# How to send data from one method in web service to another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I have a web service which contains 2 methods, one of them is for getting user name and password, and the second is method which I need to send it 3 suppliers and gets their gain.
For doing that, I need to use the first method data, and send it to the second method... but I don't know how to do it.

Below is the code that I wrote, the first code is to get the user name and password by clicking on a button, and the second is used for sending the data to the second method.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webService.TestService test = new webService.TestService();
            string result = test.GetUsernameAndPassword();
            Label1.Text = result.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is okay to use Sessions, in Button1_Click add the result to Session and in Button2_Click access result from Session. Sample code is given below.

> Note: You can store any serializable data in Session, unless you use inproc session manageemnt.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webService.TestService test = new webService.TestService();
        string result = test.GetUsernameAndPassword();
        Label1.Text = result.ToString();
        Session.Add("UsernamePassword", result);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usernamePassword = Session["UsernamePassword"] as string;
    }
```